# Minimum Cost Flow not optimizing routes

Tags: c#, algorithm, linear-programming, or-tools

I am trying to solve an engineering problem using the MinCostFlow in OR-Tools. There is a mechanical distribution system with pipes and a number of supply valves. Those valves need to be connected to consumers. Originally, I was trying to solve this with the Hungarian Algorithm, but then I realized that the flow through the path is not considered by this.

I have modeled the problem with a Min Cost Flow like this:
[image: Flow Design]

Nodes 0-4 are the Consumers, Nodes 4-7 are the supply valves, Nodes 8 and 9 are the pipes. I put a "supply" on each of the consumers to show how much flow it expects. I put a sink at the end to get the supply out of the system. Not all consumers have the same need. We can see Node 0 requires 10, and I have specifically designed a path (highlighted in red) that would allow it to carry it there. I have set all prices to 0 for now.

I would expect it to solve this system like this:
[image]

However, it actually solves it like this:

[image]

For some reason, it decides to split Node 0 across 2 Nodes (6 and 7) and then has the bigger Node 7 receiving 5 from both 3 and 0. This is not ideal from a system perspective, and I don't understand why it would solve it this way. In the Hungarian Algorithm, it would not allow a Worker to accept more than one Job. And in that algorithm, Node 4-7 would be Workers and 0-3 would be the Jobs.

I can get the desired result by increasing the cost of the arcs from Nodes 1-3 to node 7, but I do not want to manipulate the cost field to get the desired result. This seems like a lot of extra work to help the optimization tool select the right path.

How do I use OR-Tools to accomplish this?

Comment: Does "splits not ideal" mean that you *need* a 1-1 mapping, or does it mean that splits should cost more?  Also, are there really only two pipes or is that just an example?

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yes - I need the 1-1 mapping. A single valve can only supply one consumer. So if there is only one valve that can supply 10, it would be wasteful (and a less complete solution) if it is not assigned to the consumer who requires 10. In production, there would be 10,000 valves and 10,000 consumes with different demands and maximum flows. I'm testing small first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it simple, as soon as you want the solver to choose a path, it becomes NP complete.
Min Cost Flow is polynomial, by definition it will split flows across arcs, and not choose one of the other.

What you want is a integer linear problem. You can solve it with the CP-SAT solver, or the linear solver wrapper using CBC, or CP-SAT as a backend.